# Grouping rows from the same table into a row from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Table A**

- group_id
- my_id
- value

Let's say I have

```
group_id     my_id    value
  1            a        10
  1            b        15
  2            c        20
  3            d        25
```

I want to output

```
   group_id     my_id    value    family
      1            a        10     [10, 15]
      1            b        15     [10, 15]
      2            c        20     [20]
      3            d        25     [25]
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_agg and join

```
select t1.*,t2.family from tbl t1
  join 
    (
    select group_id,array_agg(value) as family form tbl
    group by group_id
    ) as t2 t1.group_id=t2.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a co-related scalar subquery:

```
select group_id, 
       value, 
       array(select value from the_table t2 where t2.group_id = t1.group_id) as family
from the_table t1
order by group_id;
```

Comment: Hi is "order by" important here?

Comment: @Zanko: that depends. Your desired output lists the rows ordered by `group_id`. That order is only guaranteed if you use an `order by`. So if you don't care about the order, then no it's not important. If you want to be sure you see group_id 1 before group_id 2 then yes it's important